# Compiling ZipArchive in XCode 4 project

Tags: iphone, xcode, compression, zip, xcode4

I'm trying to compile ZipArchive with my project. I imported all the source files, including the minizip files and I am at a loss to understand these errors. I've tried a dozen other ways to incorporate compression/decompression into my iphone project, all with out success. ZipArchive seems to be the best library out, and this problem looks like it's a simple build settings configuration problem but I cannot figure it out.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
  "_zipClose", referenced from:
      -[ZipArchive CloseZipFile2] in ZipArchive.o
  "_zipOpenNewFileInZip3", referenced from:
      -[ZipArchive addFileToZip:newname:] in ZipArchive.o
  "_unzOpenCurrentFile", referenced from:
      -[ZipArchive UnzipFileTo:overWrite:] in ZipArchive.o
  "_unzGetGlobalInfo", referenced from:
      -[ZipArchive UnzipOpenFile:] in ZipArchive.o
  "_unzReadCurrentFile", referenced from:
      -[ZipArchive UnzipFileTo:overWrite:] in ZipArchive.o
  "_unzOpen", referenced from:
      -[ZipArchive UnzipOpenFile:] in ZipArchive.o
  "_unzCloseCurrentFile", referenced from:
      -[ZipArchive UnzipFileTo:overWrite:] in ZipArchive.o
  "_zipWriteInFileInZip", referenced from:
      -[ZipArchive addFileToZip:newname:] in ZipArchive.o
  "_zipOpenNewFileInZip", referenced from:
      -[ZipArchive addFileToZip:newname:] in ZipArchive.o
  "_unzGoToFirstFile", referenced from:
      -[ZipArchive UnzipFileTo:overWrite:] in ZipArchive.o
  "_unzGetCurrentFileInfo", referenced from:
      -[ZipArchive UnzipFileTo:overWrite:] in ZipArchive.o
  "_zipCloseFileInZip", referenced from:
      -[ZipArchive addFileToZip:newname:] in ZipArchive.o
  "_unzClose", referenced from:
      -[ZipArchive UnzipCloseFile] in ZipArchive.o
  "_zipOpen", referenced from:
      -[ZipArchive CreateZipFile2:] in ZipArchive.o
  "_unzGoToNextFile", referenced from:
      -[ZipArchive UnzipFileTo:overWrite:] in ZipArchive.o
  "_unzOpenCurrentFilePassword", referenced from:
      -[ZipArchive UnzipFileTo:overWrite:] in ZipArchive.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Did you link with libz.dylib ?

Comment: @Benj yes. I tried it with libz.dylib and with libz.1.2.3.dylib, no effect.

Comment: Additionally, I create a clean project and import the files, linking to libz.dylib and get the same errors- so I know it isn't my project.

Comment: where to find this lib.dylib ? Is it open source ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue. I use Xcode 4.4 for iOS 5.1.
And I solved it this way:

1. Remove the all ZipArchive-Files incl. Minizip-Folder from your project - move to trash.
2. Re-Add both ZipArchive-Files and the Minitip-Folder and ENSURE YOU SELECT THE OPTION  "Create groups for any added folder" instead of "Create folder references for any added folder".
3. if you use ARC, then add to all Build Phases -> Compile Sources ZipArchive-Items the option "-fno-objc-arc"

That´s it - good luck.

Comment: I haven't looked at this since I solved this problem by choosing another solution, but it sounds like you've got the most current answer.

Comment: This resolved the ABC issues for me using Xcode Version 4.5.2 (4G2008a) targeting iOS 6.

Comment: After days I still cannot get this bloody working. What an absolute nightmarish week with ZipArchive. Not happy at all.

Answer (score 2):

When I tried it will easily compiled with following link

http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/wiki/PageName

I just take folder in following Form

```
ZipArchive 
   ZipArchive.h
   ZipArchive.mm
   minizip (Folder)
```

Then just drag & drop ZipArchive folder in to xCode "Classes".

Then add framework libz.1.2.3.dylib.

That's it. My code get compile without any issue.

Comment: try importing "ZipArchive/ZipArchive.h"

Comment: I had import "ZipArchive/ZipArchive.h" then take ZipArchive *zip = [[ZipArchive alloc] init]; then use [zip CreateZipFile2:...]; All works well. I am using Xcode 3.2.5 with iOS SDK 4.2

Comment: I'm using Xcode 4. I have finally gotten it to compile with the import, but as soon as I say ZipArchive *zip = [[ZipArchive alloc] init]; it fails with a similar error as above (although just 1 of them, instead of 16). I don't know what I did to improve it but I still can't use the library.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by adding "/usr/lib/libz.dylib" to the Other Link Flags in the targets section of Project settings.

It worked for me with Minizip.

Answer (score 0):

I also fell into this same case....

But I found the following resolution.

http://travitu.hatenablog.jp/entry/2014/12/23/005037

I solved it this way:

・When you add ZipArchive-Files and the Minitip-Folder to your project,
you should check "Copy items if needed" and "Create groups".

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by adding libz.tdb file. (Xcode 7, iOS 9). Error gone.

Comment: I didn't. Did you process any special steps ?